# Gradient как отрисовать короткий переход между цветами

Tags: android, градиент

```
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip android:clipOrientation="vertical" android:gravity="bottom">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ff8076c3"
                android:centerY="0.95"
                android:endColor="#ffff0066"
                android:angle="90"
                />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

На первом изображении показан результат данной разметки, а на втором как хочу что бы было. 
Как это реализовать?

Полностью весь пример взять вот отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926395/android-set-a-progressbar-to-be-a-vertical-bar-instead-of-horizontal

[image: Сейчас это работает так]

[image: а нужно что было вот так]